# How to dynamically scale an image in react-native?

Tags: image, react-native, expo

I want an image to appear across the width of the screen, and be scaled so it retains its proportions.

I currently have this

```
<ScrollView style={styles.background}>
<Text>Some Header Text</Text>
 <Image
    style={{width: null}}
    resizeMode="contain"
    source={require("./assets/images/map.png")}
   />
</ScrollView>
```

which half works. The image is scaled correctly in width. but it is retaining its height, so there is a large border above and below the image.(ie the layout is still using the images height unscaled)

If I add a `height: null` or replace the width with a `height` then no image is displayed.

How do I do this (I expect) trivial thing?
(same behavior on ios and android.)

Comment: Can you show screenshot how your output should look like? Do you need background image or it should be scrollable?

Comment: It should be scrollable. Just an image below a headline, that fits to the size of the screen in portrait or landscape.

Comment: can you try `style={height: 100, width: Dimensions.get('window').width} resizeMode="cover"`.

Comment: well that 'works' but fixes the height at 100px... I want that to be the full image... I could do maths I guess but cannot this happen by default?

Comment: you are in scrollview else flex: 1 would do the trick..

Comment: Can you expand on that @SagarKhatri? A code sample?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/tips-for-react-native-images-or-saying-goodbye-to-trial-and-error-b2baaf0a1a4d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have had to calculate things myself.

This scales the image as I want, and the image is re-scaled when the phone is rotated.

I am not sure if `componentWillMount` is the right event to choose to calculate the width/height ratio. I would be happy for any other code review comments!

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  Button,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import resolveAssetSource from "resolveAssetSource";
import {Actions} from "react-native-router-flux";

export default class Main extends Component {
  measureView(event) {
    this.setState({
       width: event.nativeEvent.layout.width,
       height: event.nativeEvent.layout.width
    });
  }
  componentWillMount() {        
    let source = resolveAssetSource(require("./assets/images/map.png"));
    this.setState({ratio: source.height / source.width});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView           
        onLayout={event => this.measureView(event)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.header}>
          Some Header Text
        </Text>

        <Image
          style={{
            width: this.state.width,
            height: this.state.width * this.state.ratio
          }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          source={require("./assets/images/map.png")}
        />  
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```